# Replacement for JDownloads

Tags: extensions, migration, download

I have to upgrade a J2.5 website to J3 that uses JDownloads. The issue is that JDownloads is still in beta for J3. Anyone knows of any good replacement for this component that will also provide any kind of data migration?

Comment: What features do you need?

Comment: I have used DocMan and Phoca Download - I much prefer Phoca on my 2.5x and 3.x sites. Stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I was going to suggest sticking with the current version of jDownloads on your J3.x site but it won't even work in the slightest.

I do not know of any Download Directory extensions that will allow you to import your data from jDownloads and having checked the JED site, I don't think any exist as it is a relatively big/complex extension.

I think you have 2 options here:

1. Use a completely different Download Directory extension. My suggestion would be something like [Phoca Download](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/5551). This is assuming you want an extension which more or less that has the same rich features that jDownloads has. If you would prefer something a little less complex and smaller, maybe try [OSDownloads](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/18474). I can only really recommend Phoca as it's the only one I have tried along with jDownloads. I tend to stay clear of these types of extensions as stick to custom download buttons in articles.
2. Stick with Beta 2 of jDownloads and keep updating it when an update is released. The last update for the Beta was 2 weeks ago and looking at the changelog, a lot has been done so the stable version could possible be coming out soon.

Comment: My best wish would be to use JDownloads. The budget for the project is somewhat strict, and there is an extended use of JDownloads, that's why I wanted to find the quickest possible solution. The good news on my case is that the project should be delivered around the end of July, there is sometime to wait for a newer JD release, although I would like to be able to plan everything before starting on the project. Thanks for your input anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to switch, I would also recommend Phoca Downloads.  It's free and it's stable.  I would suggest staying away from DOCman.  It has been pretty buggy since they went to version 2.0 and it gets very cumbersome on sites with lots of files.

Answer (score 2):

I have used DocMan and Phoca Download.

I prefer Phoca because;

1) Multi-Purpose Component.
2) Excellent Graphic User Interface (GUI),
3) Extremely Simple to setup and Use.
4) Comprehensive Documentation and Support.

I migrated my site from joomla docmac 2.5 to joomla 3 phoca with no issues.

FTP your files down to your local pc, set up new categories in joomla 3 phoca. FTP up your files again, you should be all sorted.

Or you could also try this extension which is also very good http://sourceforge.net/p/docman2phoca/wiki/Home/

Answer (score 2):

jDownloads 3.2 series is just on point of being stable for Joomla 3.x (and similarly for jd2.5 series on Joomla 2.5)  Recommendation by author is now to upgrade  there are articles on the upgrade from the older jD1.9 series to the latest versions.  The principle modules and plugins from jDownloads are mostly converted but extensions from other people may not be done yet.  There are many extra features in the new version.
Many of the features are listed at
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/2849